# How to call user defined function in willDrawPage hook of jsPDF-Autotable

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using below version of jsPDF and jsPDF-autotable:
"jspdf": "^2.5.1",
"jspdf-autotable": "^3.6.0",

I want to call another function from didDrawPage.

another function available in my existing component where I wrote the code of jsPDF.

[didDrawPage hooks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5p5z.png)

I tried to extending the behavior's but didn't find out the solution.